# Kill a running process inside a docker

Tags: docker, process, kill, cgroup

I've run a `find` command on a very large folder inside my docker, and now it is stuck for more than an hour.

I've tried to `kill -9` the process, and kill the docker container with `docker kill <containerid>`, but nothing helps it move. I can't run anymore commands inside the docker. The host is very responsive.

The process status is `R` (running). I can't `strace` it (strace stucks), and `kill -9` don't have any effect on it.

I've tried to look the `/proc/PID/status` file, it shows :

```
State:  R (running) 
[...]
voluntary_ctxt_switches:    2387
nonvoluntary_ctxt_switches: 29121
```

The two last numbers are increasing quite fast.

I don't care very much about that docker container or the result of the find command, but I care about the other containers on the same host.

Is there a way to nuke the process or the container without restarting the host ?

Comment: Since the host is active: Have tried sudo docker stop container_id?? and docker start container_id?

Comment: @saviour123 Yes. This command hangs. The command `docker kill` can be killed, but the container is still active.

Comment: stop the container service and start??

Answer (score 1):

when you build Docker, use this command :

```
RUN apt-get install lsof
```

then in py file you can use:

```
os.system("lsof /dev/nvidia* | awk '{print $2}' | xargs -I {} kill {}")
```

REMEMBER: this command kill all process on GPU